# Typescript (es6): SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, protractor, mocha.js

I'm having an error in `import { browser } from "protractor";` and throwing ***SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module*** in command line.

I'm using typescript, mocha and protractor.

Here's the `mochaOpts`:

```
mochaOpts: {
    bail: false,
    ui: 'bdd', 
    reporter: 'spec',
    compiler: 'ts:ts-node/register'
},
```

Here's the dependencies in package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
   "@babel/cli": "^7.7.4",
   "@babel/preset-env": "^7.7.4",
   "@babel/register": "^7.7.4",
   "@types/mocha": "^7.0.1",
   "@types/node": "^13.7.6",
   "chai": "^4.2.0",
   "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
   "graphviz": "0.0.9",
   "lodash": "^4.17.15",
   "minimist": "^1.2.0",
   "mocha": "^6.2.2",
   "npm-failsafe": "^0.4.1",
   "protractor": "^5.4.2",
   "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
   "ts-node": "^8.5.4",
   "tslint": "^5.20.1",
   "typescript": "^3.8.2",
   "typescript-logging": "^0.6.4",
   "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
   "yargs": "^13.3.0"
 }
```

Here's the tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "paths": { "*": ["types/*"] },
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "mapRoot": "./dist/out-tsc/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
beforeLaunch: function() {
        require('ts-node').register({
        project: 'tsconfig.json'
        });
    },

onPrepare: () => {
    let globals = require("protractor");
    global.browser = globals.browser;
    var chai = require("chai");
    var chaiAsPromised = require("chai-as-promised");
    chai.use(chaiAsPromised);
    global.chai = chai;
 }
```

Comment: Yup. This is because `import {browser} from 'protractor'` imports the global object at the time of the import. In the plugin section, browser is still undefined so it will not work. Once you import browser as undefined, every place where it is imported will just result in undefined. When you call `require('protractor').browser`, it brings in the object at runtime during the plugin execution. At this point, browser does exist and works. I was just about to answer this question.